# Creating a set of Python classes

Tags: python, class, data-structures, code-organization

I have a class representing a Request. I have a set of very specific requests such as "I-95", "P-22", etc. which perform distinct functions and are called by a controller class. What is the best way to do this so that one could add more requests easily down the road?

I have something like this at the moment:

```
class Requests:
    def __init__(self):
            self.types = [
                    'I-95',
                    'P-22',
                    ...
            ]

    def generate_request(self,type, Data):
            # Here I would call the appropriate case for the type, e.g. P-22
```

A Request case would be in its own separate file and look like this:

```
class P-22:
    # Members
    def __init__(self, Data):
        # Set data members
    def request(self):
        # Submit request
```

And I would be able to create a request in the controller

```
f = Requests()
f.generate_request('RC75')
```

I'm striving for something that's as clean and easily extendable as possible. Thank you!

Comment: What do you dislike about your current solution?

Comment: Well for starters I'd like to implement something akin to an enum with the list of request types. A key value pair dictionary perhaps with the name of the request as the key and a pointer to its functions as its value.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try something like:

```
class BaseRequest:
    name = None


class FooRequest(BaseRequest):
    name = 'I-95'

    def response(self):
        return "foo"


class BarRequest(BaseRequest):
    name = 'P-22'

    def response(self):
        return "bar"


class RequestManager:

    def __init__(self):
        self.requests = {
            FooRequest.name: FooRequest,
            BarRequest.name: BarRequest
        }

    def generate_request(self, name):
        if name in self.requests:
            return self.requests[name]()

    def register_request(self, request_class):
        assert issubclass(request_class, BaseRequest), \
            'Request class not a subclass of BaseRequest'
        assert hasattr('name', request_class) and isinstance(request_class.name, str), \
            'Request name not correctly configured'
        self.requests[request_class.name] = request_class
```

And then:

```
manager = RequestManager()
request = manager.generate_request('I-95')
if request is not None:
    print(request.response()) # "foo"
```

And for registering new requests:

```
class NewRequest(BaseRequest):
    name = 'N-1'

    def response(self):
        return "new"

manager = RequestManager()
manager.register_request(NewRequest)
request = manager.generate_request('N-1')
if request is not None:
    print(request.response()) # "new"
```

I personally think this is better done using a [Singleton-pattern](http://python-3-patterns-idioms-test.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Singleton.html) for the RequestManager (untested!):

```
class RequestManager:

    instance = None

    class __RequestManager:
        requests = {
            FooRequest.name: FooRequest,
            BarRequest.name: BarRequest
        }

        def generate_request(self, name):
            if name in self.requests:
                return self.requests[name]()

        def register_request(self, request_class):
            assert issubclass(request_class, BaseRequest), \
                'Request class not a subclass of BaseRequest'
            assert hasattr('name', request_class) and isinstance(request_class.name, str), \
                'Request name not correctly configured'
            self.requests[request_class.name] = request_class

    def __new__(cls):
        if not cls.instance:
            cls.instance = cls.__RequestManager()
        return cls.instance

    @staticmethod
    def getInstance():
        return RequestManager()
```

This creates a statically accessible RequestManager instance:

```
manager = RequestManager.getInstance()
# Rest same as before, register some requests, etc.

manager2 = RequestManager.getInstance() # This is actually the same manager ie. the same instance!
```

`manager` and `manager2` share the same requests dictionary, so updates via one of them applies to both (technically speaking to the same manager, because you retrieve the same instance twice)

Comment: Beautiful, 10/10, 11/10 with rice

Comment: Another question: I want a developer to be able to write a case file of their own, and add it to something like a package which contains all case files. How could I do that without them having to explicitly add the new file to the imports. I'd like for them only to have to add the file and add a new line with the name and function pointer

Comment: Updated answer to allow registering new requests

Comment: Great thank you. Can you explain how the Singleton-pattern could be applied to this scenario? I'm definitely interested in the concept.

Comment: So if I make a change to manager then manager2 will also change?

Comment: Yes, they are the same instance, so modifications apply to both.

Comment: I'm getting an error - 

AttributeError: Requests instance has no attribute "generate_request"

Comment: It looks similar to what the answer for this question is referring to: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1301346/the-meaning-of-a-single-and-a-double-underscore-before-an-object-name-in-python